# Optimising a VBA procedure that iterates over two different tables of data

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have two `sql tables` `pricetbl` and `paymenttbl`. Due to the fact that prices for item change everyday, I need to update the `paymenttbl` with prices of the right time. If a transaction is made after the `date-effective` of a product's price, then the transaction price in the `paymenttbl` is the same as the latest product's price (as long as the date-effective is smaller than transaction date). I don't only want to limit myself here, I want to iterate over the whole table to make changes to the data so every single transaction has the proper price.

```
PriceTbl 


pID| Price| Date Effective
---------------------------
1  |   10 | 01-12-2014
2  |   20 | 01-02-2015
3  |   20 | 02-12-2014
2  |   40 | 20-03-2015
1  |   50 | 02-03-2015
4  |   34 | 20-02-2015
1  |   40 | 25-05-2015

PaymentTbl

payID | pID | transDate | Price
--------------------------------
  1   |  1  | 02-12-2014| 05
  2   |  1  | 04-03-2015| 10
  3   |  2  | 21-04-2015| 35
  4   |  3  | 03-12-2014| 15
```

Expected table `paymenttbl` after running query

```
payID | pID | transDate | Price
--------------------------------
  1   |  1  | 02-12-2014| 10
  2   |  1  | 04-03-2015| 50
  3   |  2  | 21-04-2015| 40
  4   |  3  | 03-12-2014| 20
```

What will be the fastest and easiest way to retrieve and update data? My current way takes up to like  30 minutes to update the table since I iterate over the paymenttbl then I iterate over the pricetbl and compare it to each item in the paymenttbl.

My Code:

```
Function updateWorktoDateEff()
    Dim rt As DAO.Recordset
    Dim wt As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim sqlrt As String
    Dim sqlwt As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    sqlrt = "select * from pricetbl where (dailyrate IS NOT NULL)  and (dateeffective is not null) order by id, dailyrate"
    sqlwt = "select * from paymenttbl where (id > 0) order by id, date"

    Set rt = db.OpenRecordset(sqlrt)
    Set wt = db.OpenRecordset(sqlwt)

    Do While Not wt.EOF

        Do While Not ratetable.EOF
            If rt!ID = wt!ID Then
                If rt <= wt!Date Then

                        wt.Edit
                        wt!Rate = ratetable!dailyrate
                        wt.Update
                  End If
            ElseIf ratetable!ID > worktable!ID Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            rt.MoveNext
        Loop
        rt.MoveFirst
        wt.MoveNext 'move to the next worktbl record
    Loop
End Function
```

simply iterating/retrieving the data wouldn't do it. I will also need to be able to alter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way to perform this update is not to use recordsets and go row-by-row, but to use SQL to do a set-based update.  I tried writing a single update query to get there, but MS-Access got fussy about the query not being updateable, so I instead wrote two queries: one to write to a temporary table (tempNewPrices) and one to update PaymentTbl using that temporary table.

Here's the first query to create the temporary table that includes the new column NewPrice:

```
SELECT PaymentTbl.payID, PaymentTbl.pID, PaymentTbl.transDate, PaymentTbl.Price, 
(
  SELECT [Price] 
  FROM PriceTbl pr 
  WHERE pr.pID = PaymentTbl.pID 
  AND pr.[Date Effective] = (
    SELECT Max([Date Effective]) 
    FROM PriceTbl pr2 
    WHERE pr2.pID = pr.pID 
    AND pr2.[Date Effective]< PaymentTbl.[transDate]
  )
) AS NewPrice INTO tempNewPrices
FROM PaymentTbl;
```

and here's the update query to change the Price value in PaymentTbl:

```
UPDATE tempNewPrices 
INNER JOIN PaymentTbl ON tempNewPrices.payID = PaymentTbl.payID 
SET PaymentTbl.Price = [NewPrice];
```

This should be much more efficient than looping through recordsets.